# SSL decryption failed or bad record mac when running a .NET8 application in Google Cloud Run

Tags: c#, docker, ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a very basic C# application that uses no fancy dependency (only Microsoft.*) and connects to an HTTPS endpoint (namely a French public information: https://registre-national-entreprises.inpi.fr/api). This is packaged in a docker image:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# prepare rocksdbsharp
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    libc6-dev \
    libsnappy1v5 \
    zlib1g \
    libbz2-1.0 \
    libgflags2.2 \
    liblz4-1 \
    libzstd1 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y bzip2 lz4 librocksdb-dev

COPY . .

WORKDIR /app/*redacted*
RUN dotnet restore ./*redacted*.csproj
RUN dotnet publish ./*redacted*.csproj -c Release -o /out

# runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0
COPY --from=build-env /out .
COPY --from=build-env /usr/lib /usr/lib
COPY --from=build-env /usr/local/lib/ /usr/local/lib/
COPY --from=build-env /usr/local/bin/ /usr/local/bin/

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "*redacted*.dll"]
```

When I run this locally it works as a charm, both by running directly the .NET application and the docker. When I deploy it on Google Cloud Run Job though I get this error:

```
2024-03-21 14:31:10.716 CET
       ---> System.IO.IOException: The decryption operation failed, see inner exception.
2024-03-21 14:31:10.716 CET
       ---> Interop+OpenSsl+SslException: Decrypt failed with OpenSSL error - SSL_ERROR_SSL.
2024-03-21 14:31:10.716 CET
       ---> Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:0A000119:SSL routines::decryption failed or bad record mac
2024-03-21 14:31:10.716 CET
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2024-03-21 14:31:10.716 CET
         at Interop.OpenSsl.Decrypt(SafeSslHandle context, Span`1 buffer, SslErrorCode& errorCode)
2024-03-21 14:31:10.716 CET
         at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.DecryptMessage(SafeDeleteSslContext securityContext, Span`1 buffer, Int32& offset, Int32& count)
2024-03-21 14:31:10.716 CET
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2024-03-21 14:31:10.716 CET
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsyncInternal[TIOAdapter](Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-03-21 14:31:10.716 CET
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token)
2024-03-21 14:31:10.716 CET
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync(Boolean async)
2024-03-21 14:31:10.716 CET
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ChunkedEncodingReadStream.CopyToAsyncCore(Stream destination, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-03-21 14:31:10.716 CET
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent.<SerializeToStreamAsync>g__Impl|6_0(Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-03-21 14:31:10.716 CET
         at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.LoadIntoBufferAsyncCore(Task serializeToStreamTask, MemoryStream tempBuffer)
```

I have to admit I'm no expert in SSL at all... I've read several recommendations like:

> ethtool -K eth0 tso off gro off gso off ufo off

but this is not accessible in a dockerfile I guess.

> sed -i 's/MinProtocol = TLSv1.3/MinProtocol = TLSv1/' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf 
> && sed -i 's/CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2/CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1/' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf

did not solve my issue either (and anyway I guess this would be for downgrading TLS version mainly but here the endpoint server supports TLS1.3).

---

**EDIT**

I suspect this happens for queries that have large response bodies (>200KB). This happens regarless of whether I use a VPC or not, but I read somewhere this could happen with MTU parameters... Though I don't know if I can configure MTU when there's no network / subnet involved... (don't event know if that's relevant at all).

I also wonder if it could be related to some sort of quotas of Google Cloud Run (I've read the section about limit size in https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas but it seems to be about the container itself and not about the requests/responses the container makes).

Comment: To add a bit more information: the login works fine, it's only particular requests that have this issue it seems... Could it be that the responses are big (roughly 5MB)?

Comment: I wonder if it's due to big responses, for instance this request fails on Google Cloud Run Job container: https://registre-national-entreprises.inpi.fr/api/companies/diff?pageSize=1&from=2024-03-20&to=2024-03-21&searchAfter=997749510 I suspect because the response body is ~300KB... Is there any option to control this?

Comment: You have included everything but what is required. 1) Show the code that is making the request. 2) Show the HTTP request being sent to the remote. 3) Include details on the exact response. 4) If necessary setup your own endpoint/service so that you can test and log requests and responses. 5) Have you tested the container running locally or in a service such as Compute Engine + Docker? If not, do so as that will simplify testing and debugging.

Comment: 1) it fails both with C# & Python, don't think it's related to any application but more to openSSL and Google Cloud Run configuration.
2) Not much really it's a GET on the endpoint I gave in my second comment only (with auth JWT)
3) There's no response gotten by application since it fails at openSSL level (some way it thinks it's been tampered)
4) Not sure I understand
5) Yes as told: works on any local computer tested, works on local docker. I should add it works on Azure Functions. Not tested on GCE + Docker though

Comment: It is always possible that you have discovered a bug. However, OpenSSL is used by most of the planet for TLS networking. The odds are high that this is your bug or a bug with the remote service. Your post does not provide the details required to help you.

Comment: I never mentioned any bug in OpenSSL... As told there's nothing particular with the code and it's been reproduced with several languages (C#, Python and now TypeScript). My question are: is there anything I do wrong in my dockerfile to package an application that has outbound http requests? Extra SSL configuration needed maybe? And are there config/ limitations of Cloud Run Jobs that could explain the difference of behavior between this service and all the others (local, local docker, Azure Function). I don't own the endpoint service so can't provide much more info on it.

Comment: This [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help you create a question that we can help you solve.